# Why does stack trace frame not always contain filename and line number?

Tags: c#, stack-trace

When i write this code to find line which occurs error

```
// Case 1
try
{   
    var error= Convert.ToInt32("fdafa"); 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
    string fileName = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
    int lineNo = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(); 
}

// Case 2
try
{   
    throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
    string fileName = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
    int lineNo = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(); 
}
```

It is running correctly when i throw exception like this (from `Case 2`)

```
throw new Exception();
```

but any other codding errors like this (from `Case 1`)

```
var error= Convert.ToInt32("fdafa");
```

will throw exception i get response null from `fileName` and 0 from `lineNo`

What's is the difference about these two situation ?

Comment: which is another code that does not work?

Comment: Can you make your question title a little bit more concrete, please?

Comment: sorry i don't find concrete title could you give some suggestion?

Comment: Alex already made a good suggestion and edited the title on his/her own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its happening because if you throw a exception like this `throw new Exception();` you know the class that threw the exception because it was you who created it, and you have the code.

if the exception is thrown by a framework method like `Convert.ToInt32("fdafa")` you don't know the code, so, the line number and file name can not be entered.
Probably, if you go up a frame (`trace.GetFrame(1)`) your class that called the method in error, you can provide her name and line number.

For example, you may notice that if you try to look at the implementation of the Convert class, you can not.

Comment: i want to find unexcepted error's file name and line number is it possible ?

Comment: Yep, you can go up 1 frame, and probably the frame will be your class.   So you can get the line number and file name.

Answer (score 0):

Two small changes to your code will work for both cases.

```
    try
    {   
        var error= Convert.ToInt32("fdafa"); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        string fileName = trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1).GetFileName();
        int lineNo = trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1).GetFileLineNumber(); 
    }
```

That is because StackTrace frame counts are different in each case.